# No (or I can't find) sources/sxs folder on my computer - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, .net-framework, .net-3.5

I'm trying to install .Net 3.5 on Windows 10 and I've found that there's no sources/sxs folder anywhere on my computer.Either that or I'm too stupid to find it . Even when I try to download .Net 3.5 through Windows Features on my Control panel it can't find the sources 
My internet is working fine and I've done that whole thing with the group policy editor so I have no idea where to go from here.

Comment: So mount a Windows 10 .ISO and point DISM to it instead of your local SxS, which if it is missing, means Windows will be unable to repair itself so that is a problem you should figure out.  *Of course the correct location is actually `../Windows/WinSxS/...`* not `../sources/sxs/..`

Answer (score 2):

How did you install your Windows 10? If, for example, it was a USB drive with letter E: the following should be sufficient:

```
DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All /LimitAccess /Source:E:\sources\sxs
```

The file that needs to be in the sxs folder is called `microsoft-windows-netfx3-ondemand-package.cab`

A different trick is described on Technet:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mniehaus/2015/08/31/adding-features-including-net-3-5-to-windows-10/

In a PowerShell administrator prompt use the following command:

```
Add-WindowsCapability –Online -Name NetFx3~~~~
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the windows update service isn't disabled, if it is, press windows and R then type in services.msc, once the services window has popped up, look for Windows update, then enable it and set it to automatic to prevent this error to popup for any other feature.