# Fixes for 0x800f0922 don't work or trigger 0x80070003

Tags: .net-framework

I attempted to use the suggested fix for the 0x800f0922 error found at URL #1 below. I found my way to the question located at URL #2, and eventually found my way to URL #3, where I realized that part of the problem I have encountered was that the folder suggested in the original solution doesn't exist on my computer (details listed below).

---

- Edition: Windows 10 Home
- Version: 1909
- Installed on: 2020-08-28
- OS build: 18363.1198

---

I tried to implement the solutions listed at URL #3 as well as solutions found at URL #4, but to no avail. For the most part, I continued to receive the 0x800f0922 error, with the exception of the following proposed solution, which triggered the 0x80070003 error instead:

---

DISM.EXE /Online /Add-Package /PackagePath:C:\Features\Microsoft-Windows-NetFx3-OnDemand-Package.cab

---

I tried the solutions proposed at URL #5 below to fix the 0x80070003 error, but to no avail, once more triggering the original error. Some of my programs apparently require the .NET 3.5 Framework in order for me to even install them on my computer, so any help I can get in finding a way around these errors would be greatly appreciated.

---

1. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/application-management/dotnet-framework-35-installation-error
2. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/87fbb3fa-21c8-4d05-81fc-33b14b87f4de/net-framework-installation-files-folder?forum=netfxbcl
3. [No (or I can't find) sources/sxs folder on my computer - Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1114462/no-or-i-cant-find-sources-sxs-folder-on-my-computer-windows-10)
4. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mniehaus/adding-features-including-net-3-5-to-windows-10
5. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/error-code-0x80070003/20f72ae6-743b-4f68-81c3-ea027bd60d3f

---

**EDIT: Retried mounting the ISO. Managed that successfully. Retried the command to source the file from the E drive. The command and output are below.**

PS C:\windows\system32> DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All /LimitAccess /Source:E:\sources\sxs
Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.18362.1139

Image Version: 10.0.18363.1198

Enabling feature(s)
[==========================100.0%==========================]

Error: 0x800f0922

DISM failed. No operation was performed.
For more information, review the log file.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log

---

**EDIT: Result of Restorehealth command**

PS C:\windows\system32> DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.18362.1139

Image Version: 10.0.18363.1198

[==========================100.0%==========================] The restore operation completed successfully.
The operation completed successfully.

---

**Disk Partitions**
[Partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkVj3.png)

Comment: Just to confirm, if I performed that correctly, I would have 2 installations of Windows 10 on my computer?

Comment: What is the size of your system reserved partition?  I also need to see the output of `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth`